# Heroku build failed: heroku-prebuild

Tags: heroku

I've recently made updates to a project that I'm trying to deploy on. It was build successfully before, but now running into the following error messages. I'm not sure what the error is as I've already tried to delete package-lock.json, cleared npm cache and reinstall npm. Thanks in advance!

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 8.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.12.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.4.1

-----> Building dependencies
       Running heroku-prebuild

       > kickstart@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild /tmp/build_ddb0ffb55870b12204585dc338aab661
       > next build

sh: 1: next: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! kickstart@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild: `next build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the kickstart@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild script.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "kickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-prebuild": "next build",
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "start": "next build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "next": "^4.2.3",
    "next-routes": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.77.2",
    "solc": "^0.4.21",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.3",
    "web3": "1.0.0-beta.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but the problem lies in `heroku-prebuild` where you call `next build`. At this point, no dependencies are yet installed. You should run `next build` at a different stage. You already have it as `start` script.